# Mui icons doesn't work in React (Basic example Card)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, icons, jsx

```
    C:\Users\Yeap\Documents\react sitio web\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\All Users'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\All Users'
}
```

Sometimes show me a error message in browser localhost, `./src/components/Products.jsx Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore' in 'C:\Users\Yeap\Documents\react sitio web\my-app\src\components'`

**I tried this (official documentation and github issues)**

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install @material-ui/icons
npm install @material-ui/core@next @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @material-ui/icons --force

npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

But nothing works :(((

**This is the code from example "Card MUI"** [Official documentation](https://mui.com/components/cards/)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@mui/material/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import ShareIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Share';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';

const ExpandMore = styled((props) => {
  const { expand, ...other } = props;
  return <IconButton {...other} />;
})(({ theme, expand }) => ({
  transform: !expand ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(180deg)',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
  }),
}));

export default function RecipeReviewCard() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }} aria-label="recipe">
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
        subheader="September 14, 2016"
      />
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
        alt="Paella dish"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook
          together with your guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the
          mussels, if you like.
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
          <FavoriteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <ExpandMore
          expand={expanded}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more">
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </ExpandMore>
      </CardActions>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography paragraph>Method:</Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat 1/2 cup of the broth in a pot until simmering, add saffron and
            set aside for 10 minutes.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Heat oil in a (14- to 16-inch) paella pan or a large, deep skillet
            over medium-high heat. Add chicken, shrimp and chorizo, and cook,
            stirring occasionally until lightly browned, 6 to 8 minutes.
            Transfer shrimp to a large plate and set aside, leaving chicken and
            chorizo in the pan. Add pimentón, bay leaves, garlic, tomatoes,
            onion, salt and pepper, and cook, stirring often until thickened and
            fragrant, about 10 minutes. Add saffron broth and remaining 4 1/2
            cups chicken broth; bring to a boil.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Add rice and stir very gently to distribute. Top with artichokes and
            peppers, and cook without stirring, until most of the liquid is
            absorbed, 15 to 18 minutes. Reduce heat to medium-low, add reserved
            shrimp and mussels, tucking them down into the rice, and cook again
            without stirring, until mussels have opened and rice is just tender,
            5 to 7 minutes more. (Discard any mussels that don’t open.)
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            Set aside off of the heat to let rest for 10 minutes, and then
            serve.
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Collapse>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

**But nothing works :((**

I've already **tried creating new projects**, **reinstalling** the npm packages, **restarting** the pc, but it **doesn't work**.
The ***more basic example works***, but the ***three example does not*** **(official MUI website)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed `@material-ui` packages but import from `@mui` package. That wont work.

The packages you need to install is:

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

// with yarn
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Please refere to: https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/

Comment: Hmm.. i just checked the documentation and it seems you are using the correct import. Try and delete your package.lock/yarn.lock and run `npm install` / `yarn install` (depending on which packagemanager you are using)

Comment: thanks you so much, I was able to completely finish the problem. The Spanish website is out of date. that's why it was installing wrong. Thank you, your help solved the problem for me @Delice

Answer (score 0):

Mui package

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

And Mui icons (in my case)

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Wrong!!

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
npm install @material-ui/core@next @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

**this solved my problem, thanks to @Delice for helping me :)**
[image: Image working Card MUI example :)]